# latex failure ipython daft matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, ipython, daft

I was keen to try out daft (http://daft-pgm.org/) and through it I found out that latex functionality was not working in matplotlib.

I paste the example on the daft website (http://daft-pgm.org/examples/nocircles/):

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc("font", family="serif", size=12)
rc("text", usetex=True)

import daft

pgm = daft.PGM([3.6, 2.4], origin = [1.15, 0.8], node_ec="none")
pgm.add_node(daft.Node("cloudy", r"cloudy", 3, 3))
pgm.add_node(daft.Node("rain", r"rain", 2, 2))
pgm.add_node(daft.Node("sprinkler", r"sprinkler", 4, 2))
pgm.add_node(daft.Node("wet", r"grass wet", 3, 1))
pgm.add_edge("cloudy", "rain")
pgm.add_edge("cloudy", "sprinkler")
pgm.add_edge("rain", "wet")
pgm.add_edge("sprinkler", "wet")
pgm.render()
pgm.figure.savefig("nocircles.pdf")
pgm.figure.savefig("nocircles.png", dpi=150)
```

This is what ipython returns to me

```
RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:  
'lp'
Here is the full report generated by LaTeX:
```

There is no report supplied by ipython or LaTex. See screenshot:

[image]

The standard script on the matplotlib website gives me the same error. Is there a way to check if all the dependencies are met? LaTex is installed on my system but I am not sure if ipython can access it.

Comment: the lp command (http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_lp.htm) looks like it is being used to create the dvi from your latex, so it would seem you don't have it installed. What is your OS? I'm guessing from the command line you don't have access to the lp executable ("whence lp")?

Comment: i use mac ox. 10.8.4. the gui/terminal you see is the Qt console from the anaconda distribution.

Comment: it is not shown, thats the problem. there is no output given. see screenshot.

Comment: Forgetting ipython, I don't think you can access "lp" from the command line. Is that correct?

Comment: i dont know. i have experience with latex and ipython but i cant seem to get them to work together. the error says that latex is have trouble to process the *string* 'lp' so I'm assuming that it is referring to just a python object

Comment: terminal returns this :
```
$ lp
lp: Error - no default destination available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was a LaTex library that needed to be installed (sorry I didn't pay attention to which one)

It automatically opened my MikTex installer, so you install the suggested library and you should be done.

There is no need for 'lp' to be accessible from the command line.